# Why did the host say "...I WILL do some exercise..." instead of "...I do some exercise..."?

Tags: tense

This passage is from [6 minute English](https://youtu.be/8yzy7ucYcII) by the BBC:

> But because I know that is not good for my health, I do also like to go to the gym a couple of times a week and I **will** do some exercise like a bike ride, playing football at the weekend.

Why did not the host just say *I do some exercise*...? I am a little bit confused because it does not seem like a promise, but rather a habitual thing. Does the present and future tenses mean the same thing in this context, or the use of the future simple has some shade in meaning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word **will** there is the present tense counterpart of **would** when referring to regular or standard or customary practice.

> We **would** go to the beach in the summer when I was a kid.
>
> When I go the gym, usually I **will** start out with some warm-up exercises.

Comment: So does it mean the as I do some exercisd?

Comment: Yeah, customary practice but [*within an established time frame*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/the-difference-between-used-to-and-would)! : ) That little observation alone may help the rule from sounding as though it were just "another way to express customariness" and in this way aid learners in resolving their being double-minded when using this or other constructions.

Comment: @userr2684291: If I say *I will do some warm-up exercises tomorrow*, there's a clearly established time-frame, but it does not have the meaning in that sentence of the  "customary".  What needs to be established, semantically, is the sense of the customary, or the usual.  *Usually I'll start off with stretching when I go to the gym.*

Comment: Hm, yeah, I guess that's it. There has to be at least a tinge of *normally, regularly* somewhere before, in order that your *will* be understood similarly. Notice how they consider *I would watch cartoons every Saturday morning when I was very little* ungrammatical, while the following is fine: *When I was little, I would get up and watch cartoons every Saturday morning*? Your first example sentence looks awfully like the former to me. They might be overreacting with their pronouncements of ungrammaticalness, however.

Comment: @userr2684291.  You are understating the matter when you say that they're "overreacting" when pronouncing this ungrammatical:  *I would watch cartoons every Saturday morning when I was very little.*